# How to prevent SectionList from breaking for a large list?

Tags: react-native

I have a SectionList that renders both Rows and SectionHeaders, using data from a list that is huge (~3000 items). This is the bug that I am facing:

[image: The list breaks somewhere in the middle of the list, with sections flashing and scrolling erratic]

The list breaks somewhere in the middle of the list, with sections flashing and scrolling becomes erratic.

I am not sure of the getItemLayout property being used correctly, here is the function:

```
getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
        length: moderateScale(150),
        offset: moderateScale(150) * index,
        index,
      })}
```

The length of my section header is moderateScale(60) and of my row item is moderateScale(150). I am using react-native-size-matters library to compute the value of the specified sizes.

Please help me figure out where I am going wrong, or if there is a better alternative to SectionList.

Comment: `getItemLayout` is only good when all your elements are of the same size. Why do you need to use this prop ?

Comment: I was using scrollToRef, on pressing a button, I was automatically scrolling to that section. But that's not possible without using getItemLayout, right?

Comment: Check if this package helps you with that https://github.com/slorber/react-native-scroll-into-view.